# Lists contain floats and not the objects that are intended

Tags: python, oop

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/BlackJack/Main.py", line 50, in <module>
    player = Player("Player" + str(i))
  File "C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\BlackJack\Player.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.score = self.calculate_hand(self.hand)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\BlackJack\Player.py", line 21, in calculate_hand
    rank = i.get_card_value()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get_card_value'
```

The problem is that the index I am accessing is being recognised as a 'float' but the list should not contain floats, but instead contain 'Card' objects. What confuses me even more is that in the PyCharm IDE, when I write 'index.' to access attributes, it suggests 'get_card_value' as an attribute (function) available to use. This contradicts the error saying that the index (which appears to be a float) has no attribute 'get_card_value'.

---

**Main.py**

```
player = Player("Player" + str(i))
```

---

**Player.py**

class Player:
    name: string
    hand: Deck
    score: int = 0

```
def __init__(self, name: string):
    self.name = name
    self.hand = Deck("player")
    self.score = self.calculate_hand(self.hand)

@staticmethod
def calculate_hand(hand):
    cards = hand.get_deck()
    value: int = 0
    for i in cards:
        rank = i.get_card_value()
        value = value + rank
    return value
```

---

**Card.py**

```
class Card:
suit: string
rank: string
card_suits: string = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
card_ranks: string = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

def __init__(self, suit: string, rank: string):
    self.suit = suit
    self.rank = rank

def get_card(self):
    return [self.rank, self.suit]

def get_rank(self):
    return self.rank

def get_suit(self):
    return self.suit

def get_card_value(self):
    rank = self.get_rank()
    value: int = self.card_ranks.index(rank) + 1
    return value
```

---

**Deck.py**

```
import random
import string
from Card import Card
import Deck

class Deck:

card_sequence = []
deck_type = ""

def __init__(self, deck_type):
    card_suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    card_ranks = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    card_sequence = []
    for i in card_suits:
        for j in card_ranks:
            new_card = Card(i, j)
            card_sequence.append(new_card)
    self.deck_type = deck_type
    if self.deck_type == "player":
        for _ in range(2):
            self.card_sequence.append(random.choice(card_sequence))

    elif self.deck_type == "game":
        for i in card_sequence:
            self.card_sequence.append(i)

    elif self.deck_type == "burn":
        self.size = 0
        self.card_sequence = []

def draw_card(self, deck: Deck):
    draw = deck.get_top_card()
    deck.pop(draw)
    deck.size = deck.size - 1
    self.card_sequence.append(draw)

def get_deck(self):
    return self.card_sequence

def get_item(self, card_sequence_index):
    if card_sequence_index > self.size - 1:
        print("ERROR item doesn't exist")
        return

def get_top_card(self):
    item: int = self.card_sequence[0]
    return item

def get_card(self, deck):
    card = deck.get_front_item()
    self.card_sequence.push(card)
    card.pop()
    return card

def add_card(self, item):
    if item is None:
        self.card_sequence.push(item)

def remove_card(self):
    self.card_sequence.pop()
```

Comment: What's the code for `hand`?

Comment: `hand.get_deck()` returns an iterable of `int`s and not of `cards`

Comment: @EmandM Updated question.

Comment: @RafaelC No worries! Why does it return an iterable of ints and not cards?

Comment: Have no idea, you didn't post the code for `hand.get_deck`

Comment: @RafaelC I have updated my question. It's under the Deck.py section of the question. A hand is a Deck object. The Deck class has the function get_deck().

Comment: This line: `self.card_sequence.append(random.choice(card_sequence))` is appending a float to your collection. Then, later when you do `for i In cards:`, `I` takes place to be one of these floats, and you cant call `i.get_card_value` if `i` is a float

Comment: @RafaelC That makes sense. Thanks for finding the problem! Now I'll try find a solution. My only issue is that at least from my understanding, random.choice can be applied to lists of any type...